# How to capture multiple regex matches within a section bracketed by a beginning and ending statement

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture every instance of a specific value in a specific section of a text file, but only in that section and I'm not sure how to go about it.

An example would be capturing all the instances of "Banana" in only "Section2" of the following text

```
Section1
Cat Dog Bear Banana Orange
Cat Dog Bear Banana Car

Section2
Cat Dog Bear Banana Waffle
Cat Dog Bear Banana Truck

Section3
Waffle Bear Bear Banana Truck
Cat Dog Bear Banana Pie
```

I'm pretty sure I should be starting off with a noncapturing group for Section2 `(?:Section2)` something, then a capturing block for Banana `(Banana)`, something then another non capturing group for Section 3 `(?:Section3)`. It's the two somethings though that are causing me issue.

Could anyone reccomend me how to create a regular expression to match all instances of something but only within a section of text marked by a section beginning and end?

Comment: This is all done within Reqtracer which uses Perl regular expressions

Comment: Does [`(?:^Section2$|(?<!^)\G).*?\KBanana(?=.*^Section3$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Uy3nJW/1) work for you?

Comment: Yes that seems to do it, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex using `\G` (boundary anchor):

```
(?:^Section2$|(?<!^)\G).*?\KBanana(?=.*^Section3$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uy3nJW/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capturing group

  - `^Section2$`: Match a line with `Section2`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?<!^)\G`: assert end of previous match
- `)`: End non-capturing group
- `.*?`: Match zero or more of anything (lazy)
- `\K`: Reset matched data
- `Banana`: Match literal text `Banana`
- `(?=.*^Section3$)`: Lookahead to assert, we have `Section3` ahead.

Comment: Good job : I didn't understand `(?<!^)\G`

Comment: `\G` is called boundary anchor that asserts position at the start OR at the end of previous match. `(?<!^)` is negative lookbehind that makes sure we don't match `\G` at the start.